# embed Flashplayer in Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, flash

How can I embed the Flash player into a webpage using a **Custom Url** . Doing this with Iframes instead of using object tags in the html.Would I need to use javascript to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you can't simply use the src attribute like:

```
<iframe width="100px" height="100px" src="youSwfFile.swf"></iframe>
```

Comment: the flash player would be over the top of the iframe

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use jQueryTools flashembed(), this allows you to embed a flash object into a div... Which may be a good starting point for you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //jquery call to embed flash object,
    flashembed("#frameID", {src: "the-SWF-URL",wmode:"opaque"});
    //set width and height - ffox fix
    $('#frameID').css({'width':'564px','height':'160px','z-index':'-1'});
});
```

for more info and options - http://jquerytools.org/documentation/toolbox/flashembed.html

Comment: If you use jQuery for other stuff then yes, but otherwise there are other JavaScript libraries better suited for the task, i.e. swfobject, that is more or less the de facto standard for embedding swf content. http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/